# Is it possible to name the get variable with a . operator?

Tags: php, get

I think this is simple question , I am having trouble in passing a variable with a . in the name for example

```
www.example.com/index.php?auth.start=facebook
```

if I change this url to

```
www.example.com/index.php?authstart=facebook
```

and I try to get the variable like this

```
$var = $_GET[authstart];

echo $var;
```

It works fine , But

```
 $var = $_GET[auth.start];

 echo $var;
```

this shows no value in `$var` can any one help me out with this

thanks in Advance

Comment: I do hope your actual code quotes the array keys... right?

Comment: Try `$_GET['auth.start'];`

Comment: Are you using a `.` *operator* or just have a `.` *in the string*?  There's a pretty significant difference, and your question doesn't make it very clear.

Comment: ffs, enable displaying warnings...

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: And take a look at the title of the question.  And take a look at the lines of PHP code in the question.  One statement is clear, but the question as a whole contains multiple conflicting statements.

Comment: The real answer here is: just don't put `.` in your URL vars, and save yourself the headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `$_GET["auth_start"]`

Hope that helps :)

Comment: @Azrael surprisingly, this answer is correct.

Comment: I'd even say sadly. But it is correct. Although no + because of the encouragement of omitting the quotes

Comment: @fejese you are right, in my debug I put quotes, but when I copied the question, I did forget. Now it is fixed. thank you

Comment: I said nothing. read the question wrong in combination with this awnser.

Comment: @Azrael deleting your comment is not the same as saying nothing ;).

Answer (score 1):

A `.` in a variable name is not valid in PHP, so with `$_GET` PHP will convert the `.` to a `_`.  It does this because `register_globals` will extract the `$_GET` array into individual PHP variables which can't contain the `.`.

Doing `print_r($_GET)` will show you this.

User defined arrays work fine: `$a['x.y'] = 1` etc...

Answer (score 0):

Array keys are strings. While php may forgive you sometimes for omitting them, they should be enclosed. so always do

```
$_GET['yourkey'];
```

and never

```
$_GET[yourkey];
```

in your case, this is the correct syntax:

```
 $var = $_GET['auth.start'];
```

But then, as @AbraCadaver says, that will also not work, for you `.` is changed to a `_`.

So use

```
 $var = $_GET['auth_start'];
```

To go a bit deeper: if you don't actually make it a string, you'll get this notice:

> PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant yourkey - assumed 'yourkey'

Comment: Even I'm interested in why the down vote?

Comment: Wow, I just tried it and what @AbraCadaver said in his answer is true. `$_GET` variables are treated as variables not simple array keys ...

Comment: I downvoted because it is incorrect.

Comment: incomplete you mean. fixed that, good point. But so is yours, as arrays still need a string as key.